# How do I get Java AWS SDK version from code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I have my Java code running in some managed environment that provides AWS SDK. I found out that some methods on classes are unavailable in that environment compared to documentation for recent version of AWS SDK.

Is there a way to programmatically find out version of AWS SDK that is available? Is there any information class that provides such information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for the method [getVersion()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/VersionInfoUtils.html#getVersion--) in the class [VersionInfoUtils](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/VersionInfoUtils.html).

From the linked documentation:

Signature:

```
public static String getVersion()
```

Description:

> Returns the current version for the AWS SDK in which this class is running. Version information is obtained from from the versionInfo.properties file which the AWS Java SDK build process generates.