# How do I get Java AWS SDK v2 version from code? (ie 2.20.34)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, version

Same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617523/how-do-i-get-java-aws-sdk-version-from-code/40734051#40734051) except for this question is for the [v2 sdk](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html).

> I have my Java code running in some managed environment that provides AWS SDK. I found out that some methods on classes are unavailable in that environment compared to documentation for recent version of AWS SDK.
>
> Is there a way to programmatically find out version of AWS SDK that is available? Is there any information class that provides such information?

I've tried looking in the [Github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2) as well as the [API docs](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html)  but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Checking with the SDK team if V2 has an equilivant class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be want you are looking for:

[software.amazon.awssdk.core.util.VersionInfo](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/util/VersionInfo.html)

Comment: Thank you! I really don't know how I missed that being present.